# Graphical bar presentation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please provide a reference for implementing a graphical representation for grid data values... if grid data is updated graphs need to update.... using jquery

Comment: This may be a start (Flot library): http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but have you had a look at D3?

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

It is a great library for graphical representations (in svg or on canvas) and it is easy to make it respond to data updates and plays well with jquery.